# Moving a character in a table

Tags: c

I just started learning programming languages and I want to make a character (point '*') in a table move.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int v;
    int x = 50, y = 10;
    int i, j;
    char screen[80][25];

    // declare and initialize table
    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            screen[i][j] = ' ';

    // coordinate system
    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) screen[i][12] =  '-';
    for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) screen[40][j] =  '|';

    // point, position
    screen[x][y] = '*';

    // print result
    for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            printf("%c", screen[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This prints a table of size 80x25 and a coordinate system with a centre in (40,12). I set the position of the character '*' on coordinates (x,y). I defined x and y as 50 and 10.

Now I want to move my star by changing x and y. 
How do I change x and y (position of the star)?
Maybe with scanf function? I tried to use scanf like this:

```
int v;
...
scanf("%d", &v);
if(v == 1)
{
    y--;
}
```

but then everything (table, coordinate system and the character) disappeared. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to 'redraw' the table each time you move the '*'.

Comment: Also, one of your variable is declared as scren, but used in code as screen!

Comment: Which platform are you on and which compiler are you using, please?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu terminal for compiler and notepad++ for editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using [[n]curses(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=curses&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses
- http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/
- http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Curses.pdf

If you are on a *nix or OS X, it should be already installed. If you are on Windows, you can get a distribution of [PdCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses) at

- http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses
- documentation: http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt

However, from a design perspective, you should separate your *model* (an 80 x 25 array ) from the *user interface*. you have two tasks:

1. Maintain the model by responding to user events.
2. Maintain the user interface by responding to changes in the model.

This leads you to a *design pattern* called *Model-View-Controller* or *MVC*. In classic MVC, you have:

- A *model*, essentially a headless application with no user interface.
- A *view*, the user interface. In your case, you have a console/terminal window as the output and a keyboard as the input, right?
- A *controller*. The job of the controller is to wire up the view to the model. The controller relays events (such as input events such as a key press or the entry of a line of text) to the model. The model responds to the event be reacting appropriately and notifies the controller if its visual state has changed. The controller, in turn, responds by instructing the view (or the required parts of the view) that its state has changed so it may re-render itself.

This *separation of concerns* makes it (among other things) simpler to write and test the code in the first place.